# Is this circuit from a textbook wrong?

Tags: digital-logic, schematics, ttl, tri-state

(This is not a homework question.)

While reading ["Digital Computer Electronics" by Albert P. Malvino](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0074622358), I found this circuit on page 121, figure 8-22(a). It claims to be an example of a discrete TTL tri-state buffer, but I believe it to be wrong.

Best I can tell, the output will always be either high or tristated: it will never be low. I also simulated it online, and the results agreed with this assessment. I googled for published errata, but found none.

Would people say this circuit was in error, or am I missing something crucial?

[image: photograph of textbook]

Comment: It won't work for driving TTL.  Connect it to a TTL input.   It cannot sink the required negative 2mA.    It would only work with mos input, and then only if a pulldown resistor was added to Dout.   (TTL inputs have no such pulldown resistor!)

Comment: It won't work for driving CMOS either. Or anything with any sort of pullup.

Answer (score 3):

For true TTL tri-state operation the output must be able to pull up *and* down. The circuit in your book can only pull up, which is not compatible with TTL logic.

Here is a real tri-state TTL (inverting) buffer:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fImmQv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When `Enable` is high Q3 is turned on, which turns off Q5 via D1, and Q4 and Q6 via Q1B. Q6 provides the essential pull down when not tri-stated.

Comment: This is pretty much what I figured. Without a pull-down, there are only two states. It's essentially the opposite of an open-collector gate. So the author is wrong, and the other answerers of this question are wrong.

Comment: It doesn’t actually say that it is TTL logic compatible anywhere in the text.

Comment: @metacollin the OP says that it does. 7400 gates are mentioned in a later paragraph, but the text is cut off in the photo so its relevance can't be verified. That is why I was careful to **not** state that the textbook was wrong. In any case it's a poor example. Why talk about tri-state TTL right after showing a dodgy circuit that isn't TTL compatible?

Answer (score 1):

Upon finding the original textbook online and reviewing the wording, my  previous answer was incorrect so, **I reversed my opinion.** Apologies for the Senior's moment.

## This is NOT a 3 state switch.  The text is incorrect.

There is no active open collector to pull down the bus to 0V < 100 ohms for a logic "0"  or even 10k for high Zin.

[image]
 [image]